# Replace Text with time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Need help

1. When any link is clicked the text (not clicked ) should be replaced by the time.

   ```
   <div><a href="http://facebook.com">Facebook(NOT CLICKED)</a></div>
   <div>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="http://youtube.com">Youtube(NOT CLICKED)</a></li>
       </ul>
   ```

Comment: Post some of your HTML not links to facebook and youtube!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I have updated it

Comment: If the links are clicked you'll be redirected and any changes will be lost! Do you want to prevent the default behavior of the clicks?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes

Answer (score 1):

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
links.forEach(function(l) {
  l.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
});

function clickHandler(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // don't redirect (don't go the the link in the href)
  
  this.textContent = this.textContent.replace("(NOT CLICKED)", "(" + Date() + ")"); // replace the text "(NOT CLICKED)" with "(date)"
}
```

```html
<div><a href="http://facebook.com">Facebook(NOT CLICKED)</a></div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://youtube.com">Youtube(NOT CLICKED)</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```